# Complicated DIFF method

Tags: linux, shell, awk, python, diff

I'm trying to do a compare between a config from an old box and a new box to verify Availability and State haven't changed.

I have a file that is generated with about a thousand nodes but every node has these lines (value is different).  So my goal is when I run my compare/diff script I want to pull value for lines..
first line I just need Ltm::Node: (value between braces)

```
Availability (keep value after :)
State (keep value after :)
Reason (keep value after :)
Monitor (keep value after : but if exists do not include (default node monitor)
Monitor Status (keep value after :)
```

---

```
--------------------------------------------------
Ltm::Node: Development/10.47.63.133 (10.47.63.133)
--------------------------------------------------
Status
  Availability   : available
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : Node address is available
  Monitor        : /Common/icmp (default node monitor)
  Monitor Status : up
```

Here is a few old

```
Ltm::Node: Common/splunk-hec1-p.mwg.com (::)
  Availability   : unavailable
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : No records returned
  Monitor        : /Common/icmp (default node monitor)
  Monitor Status : fqdn-up-no-address
Ltm::Node: Common/_auto_10.72.7.122 (10.72.7.122)
  Availability   : unknown
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : Node address does not have service checking enabled
  Monitor        : Common/none
  Monitor Status : unchecked
Ltm::Node: Common/_auto_10.72.12.148 (10.72.12.148)
  Availability   : unknown
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : Node address does not have service checking enabled
  Monitor        : Common/none
  Monitor Status : unchecked
```

Here is a few new so you can see the differences (minor but difficult since compare shows difference in name)

```
Ltm::Node: splunk-hec1-p.mwg.com (::)
  Availability   : unavailable
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : No records returned
  Monitor        : /Common/icmp (default node monitor)
  Monitor Status : fqdn-up-no-address
Ltm::Node: _auto_10.72.7.122 (10.72.7.122)
  Availability   : unknown
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : Node address does not have service checking enabled
  Monitor        : Common/none
  Monitor Status : unchecked
Ltm::Node: _auto_10.72.12.148 (10.72.12.148)
  Availability   : unknown
  State          : enabled
  Reason         : Node address does not have service checking enabled
  Monitor        : Common/none
  Monitor Status : unchecked
```

Why?  migration from an old box to new box, the old box didn't follow any standard naming conventions and the new box does so the name Development/10.47.63.133 (or whatever it is) is almost a guarantee to be different.

I thought of exporting all info into a .txt file (which the above is a snippet from file) from legacy box and do the same thing on new box and run a script that does a diff to look for any differences.  HOPE is to show what doesn't match so I can quickly attack and look for a solution.

someone suggested AWK..  I tried diff and that I can show all lines but I have over a thousand nodes and would take too long.  Trying to use Ltm::Node: (10.47.63.133) as the index that will match between old and new and all the stuff underneath will be what is compared to see if anything doesn't match.

Sorry for the confusion..  wasn't sure how to describe this headache.

Comment: Showing 1 node from 1 file isnt an adequate example - if you want help diff-ing 2 files which each contain multiple nodes then you need to provide sample input that is 2 files containing multiple nodes plus the expected output given that input. Otherwise we have nothing to copy/paste to test a potential solution against. Please [edit] your question to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) making sure it covers all of your use cases including missing lines, lines with differences, lines out of order, duplicate lines in 1 file, etc

Comment: You've now shown 2 input files, thanks, but you still haven't provided the expected output given that input. Please [edit] your question to add that. Don't just describe the expected output, **show** the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of data can be processed fairly easily as a multi-level associative array (or Hash-of-Hashes / HoH in perl terminology, see [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc), the perl Data Structures Cookbook), with the first level key being the node name and the second-level keys (which I'm calling the "sub-key" in the script below) being the relevant field names (Availability, State, Reason, etc).

For example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

die "Usage $0 [oldfile] [newfile]\n" unless (@ARGV == 2) ;

# remember both filename args
my ($oldfile,$newfile) = @ARGV[0,1];

die "$oldfile is not readable or does not exist\n" unless -r $oldfile;
die "$newfile is not readable or does not exist\n" unless -r $newfile;

# Hash variables to hold old and new data
my (%old, %new);

# Hash reference variable pointing to the hash we want
# the main loop to populate at any given moment.
# Starts off pointing to %old, changes to %new after the
# first file reaches end-of-file.
# See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut and
# https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref
my $hashref = \%old;

# variable to hold the name of the current node name as
# the records in the input files are read in.
my $node;

# read and parse input files
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  s/^\s*|\s*$//g; # strip leading and trailing whitespace
  s/\s+:\s+/ : /; # strip excess whitespace around first :

  if (/^Ltm::Node:.*\s+\((.*)\)/) {
    $node = $1;
    $hashref->{$node}{name} = $node;
  } elsif (/ : /) {
    my ($key, $val) = split / : /,$_, 2;
    $hashref->{$node}{$key} = $val
  } else {
    print STDERR "Unknown data '$_' on line $. of $ARGV\n";
  };

  if (eof) {
    close(ARGV);       # reset line counter
    $hashref = \%new;  # start populating %new instead of %old
  }
};

# compare the keys from both files
my @common_keys = ();
foreach my $k (keys %old) {
  if (exists($new{$k})) {
    push @common_keys, $k;
  } else {
    print "Node $k found in $oldfile but not in $newfile\n"
  };
};

foreach my $k (keys %new) {
  if (! exists($old{$k})) {
    print "Node $k found in $newfile but not in $oldfile\n";
  };
}

# The list of sub-keys we care about.
my @subkeys = ('Availability', 'State', 'Reason', 'Monitor',
               'Monitor Status');

# now compare sub-keys in each of the nodes
foreach my $k (@common_keys) {
  foreach my $sk (@subkeys) {
    if ($old{$k}{$sk} ne $new{$k}{$sk}) {
      printf "[%-15s %-14s] Old = \"%s\", new = \"%s\"\n", $k, $sk,
        $old{$k}{$sk}, $new{$k}{$sk};
    }
  }
}
```

Save this as, e.g. `compare.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x compare.pl` and run it like this:

```
$ ./compare.pl old.txt new.txt  
Node 10.72.12.150 found in old.txt but not in new.txt
Node 10.72.12.149 found in new.txt but not in old.txt
[10.72.12.148    State         ] Old = "enabled", new = "xenabled"
[10.72.7.122     Reason        ] Old = "Node address does not have service checking enabled", new = "xNode address does not have service checking enabled"
```

Note: Apart from minor differences on the `Ltm::Node` lines, the data in both of your input files was identical, so I had to make some differences by editing new.txt to add an `x` before some fields.  I also added node 10.172.12.150 to old.txt and 10.172.12.149 to new.txt.

Also worth noting, perl hashes are inherently unordered so the output may print the node differences in a different order on each run.  It would be easy enough to get a consistent order by sorting `%old` while populating the `@common_keys` array, but you'd have to implement a natural-sort/version-sort subroutine (or use one of the [natural sort modules](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=natural+sort) on [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/)) for the IP addresses to sort correctly.  I'll leave that enhancement as an exercise for the reader - it's not necessary for this example.

You can edit the print statements to change the output to suit your needs.  You didn't specify the output, so I just printed what seemed necessary to easily identify the differences.

It wouldn't be difficult to write something similar in awk (especially GNU awk, as it has reasonable support for multi-dimensional arrays) but I prefer perl even if it tends to be a bit more verbose than awk (actually partly **because** of that).